# Input validation (do while loop)

Tags: java

I need to make sure the value entered for the prompt is in between 100,000 and 900,000, and this isn't working, any ideas? (I'm only a beginner btw)

```
    double advertCost;
    do {
    System.out.println("Please enter the advertising cost: ");
    advertCost = input.nextDouble();

    } while (advertCost =< 100000 || advertCost => 900000);
```

The error I get:
    Syntax error on token "<", delete this token
    The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean
    Syntax error on token "=", delete this token

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is in your syntax:

```
while (advertCost =< 100000 || advertCost => 900000);
```

In Java, the "less than or equal to" operator is as you say it. LESS THAN or EQUAL to. You've got EQUAL TO or LESS THAN. Same goes for your greater than as well. It should look like this:

```
while (advertCost >= 100000 || advertCost <= 900000);
```

Also, you had your operators the wrong way around. You want `advertCost` to be greater than 100000 and less than 900000 but your operators imply less than 100,000 and greater than 900,0000.

**Just an aside about your error**

Often these sorts of issues can be understood by the error message. I know that they can seem cryptic but if you learn to decipher them, you really will have little need for us in terms of syntax errors.

`Syntax error on token "<", delete this token The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean Syntax error on token "=", delete this token`

Let's cut it up into it's parts:

**The first part**

*Message*:`Syntax error on token "<", delete this token`

Well, the JRE has just parsed your code, and it is going through each [token](http://classof1.com/homework_answers/computer_science/java_tokens/). This is the first token it has reached that is invalid, so this message is generated. However, if you delete this, you'll still have an invalid if statement, so let's read on.

**The second part.**

*Message*:`The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean`

Well, no detectable operator has been found, so the JRE has to assume there isn't one there. When it has parsed part of the IF statement it's found:

```
if(a number || something else).
```

At this point it knows that the `||` operator only works on two boolean values, so it throws another error. It does this because it already knows the code will fail; it doesn't need to check the other side.

**The last part**

*Message*:`Syntax error on token "=", delete this token`

So the JRE has continued parsing, and it's also found your "=>". As before, it's noted the invalid character and recommended you remove it. If you do remove the "=", then you actually have valid syntax for this part of the If statement.

**Summary**

Next time you're faced with this type of error, simply try to break down the message. It tells you what characters are wrong, `<` and `=`. It even tells you what to try with them. Obviously it can only guess, so it's down to you to work out what you want and how to make the Runtime Environment understand that!

Comment: Please read my edit about understanding error messages. It might help you in the future! :) PS: Please mark this as correct so people don't keep looking at it! :)

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operators are `<=` and `>=`, not `=<` and `=>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(advertCost <= 100000 || advertCost >= 900000)
```